# Expose WCF in mef plugin with Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mef

I would like to implement the next scenario:

ASP.Net MVC working with MEF in a similar manner as described [by hammett](http://blogs.msdn.com/hammett/archive/2009/07/15/mef-and-asp-net-mvc-sample-updated.aspx).

One of the things I need to allow, is the MEF Plugin contains a WCF service (or asmx service - backwords compatibility).

What approach can I use - if any - to make the MVC website grab the webservice and expose it as such: http://websitename/MefPlugin/Service1.mvc.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you can achieve this, with the following few steps:

1) Create a common class library with contracts (interfaces)

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISimpleService
{
}
```

2) Create another class library for your WCF service implementation, and mark your WCF service class with MEF's export attribute.

```
[Export(typeof(ISimpleService))]
public class SimpleService: ISimpleService
{
}
```

3) Then in your host application (ASP.NET MVC in this case) create an MEF composition container based on an assembly catalog for example.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(...);
  var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
  container.ComposeParts(this);
}
```

4) Then you will be able to import your service implementation with MEF

```
[Import]
public ISimpleService SimpleService { get; set; }
```

5) Then you can create the WCF service host for that service implementation

```
var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(SimpleService, ...);
```

Hope this helps.